# How can I load a C# dll into a C# dll Project from a dynamic location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

The Program ClosedSourceProgram starts and copies my files into an unknown location. Their Structure will be:

```
?\project.dll
?\project\usefultools.dll
```

I have to load the usefultools.dll into my project but i dont know how i can tell C#VS2010 that the dll location will be

```
project\usefultools.dll
```

---

I added the library to my assembly as a reference so that its content is known during developement - therefor it tried to load earlier than i could load it via `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.

I manually copied the file for now into the ClosedSourceProgram-root directory. It now loads without `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.

current working tree:

```
?\ClosedSourceProgram\ClosedSourceProgram.exe
?\ClosedSourceProgram\usefultools.dll
?\ClosedSourceProgram\temp\project.dll
```

the tree i want:

```
?\ClosedSourceProgram\ClosedSourceProgram.exe
?\ClosedSourceProgram\temp\project.dll
?\ClosedSourceProgram\temp\project\usefultools.dll
```

I would like to tell my project that it should search subdirectories if it cant find the dll in the root directory - how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can load an assembly from an arbitrary location *at runtime* using [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx), and passing a filename.

---

Edit:

Another option is to subscribe to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event, and load the assemblies on demand.  This has the advantage of allowing for *any* structure, since all undiscovered assemblies can loaded as needed by you.

Comment: I edited the question. Assembly.LoadFrom() is not what i want but could work.

Comment: thanks - but this is still not what i am looking for. I actually dont want to load it during runtime since i want to have it in my assembly during developement without any additional effort. This is the case rigth now - all i want to change is the defaultlocation the library is searched in. So i am basically looking for some kind of project property.

Comment: @Johannes The only other thing similar is PrivateBinPath, which can be set in App.config see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Comment: I can see that you are putting a lot of effort into this abd i thank you for this. But i have the assumtion that the solution can not be in runtime code. No function is called before the crash - the library location has to be known at buildtime, and i do know its relative path at build time.

Comment: @Johannes If it's a matter of not loading the libraries, you *can* handle it at runtime via AssemblyResolve.  The CLR doesn't have a means of doing this at build time...

Answer (score 2):

You could always try [`Assembly.LoadFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)

Comment: I edited the question. Assembly.LoadFrom() is not what i want but could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "~" operator if the assembly is with in any of the subfolders
of the application path.

Assembly.LoadFrom("~\project\usefultools.dll");

Comment: Can I use the ~ operator somehow with my normal references, so that the dll is searched in subdirectories?